# How do I build an Amazon Lex Bot using the rest API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_Operations_Amazon_Lex_Model_Building_Service.html
you can create or update bots and intents/slots (Put{Bot|Intend|Slot}, Create{Bot|Intend|Slot}Version).

So by using Put* I can configure a bot and with Create*Version I can publish one, but in order to publish it, first you need to build it and I can't find an API method for that.

Comment: I guess it's not available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `PutBot` you can supply the `--process-behavior` flag with value `BUILD` to force a build.

From the documentation:

> If you set the `processBehavior` element to `Build`, Amazon Lex builds the bot so that it can be run. If you set the element to `Save` Amazon Lex saves the bot, but doesn't build it. If you don't specify this value, the default value is `Save`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line in your json file if you are using CLI:

> "processBehavior": "BUILD",

It will build the bot.